# Nginx proxied image substitution

Tags: nginx, proxy

I have Nginx configured as transparent proxy for image files which are loaded from another domain:

```
location ^~ /image/ {
    proxy_set_header Host images.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://images.example.com:80;
}
```

I need to detect some known images and replace them with another one on the fly.

Is there a way to detect needed image in response by some criteria?
Maybe it's possible to get some checksum (crc32, md5) of the response, or maybe there's some library to analyze images (I know there's image_filter module but it's only processes images, doesn't analyze).

Comment: Can you detect them by uri?

Comment: If possible, try to detect them by response headers. And there is lua module and [body_filter_by_lua](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#body_filter_by_lua)